# How to imitate Break feature(Alt-B) from teraterm in mobaxterm.

Tags: console, mobaxterm

In MobaXterm, I am able to send Break, by Right-Click on console -> Special Command -> Break, but this is not similar to what is send in teraterm where we can hold Alt+B until we need to send Break.
Is there any similar option in MobaXterm ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. Ctrl+Pause/Break does the same in MobaXterm